# How do I implement the GWS library in xamarin for android?

Tags: graphics, xamarin.android, gws

Body: I want to use [this](https://github.com/MnMInfoTech/GWS) library using xamarin so I can run my code on an android device, the page says it's cross-platform. Does anyone have any experience with this? I'm not really sure on how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done an implementation of the library in Xamarin.Android, you can find the project on github here.

https://github.com/MananAdhvaryu/GWSAndroid

If you have any follow-up questions, please feel free to ask me in the comments.